# Problems with SVG fill="url(#)"

Tags: svg, linear-gradients

I'm dynamically creating several SVGs which have the same structure.

The problem I am running into is that I must reference gradients by their ID, and so when there are multiple SVGs, the IDs collide and cause unexpected results. **Is there a way to reference SVG elements other by a ID?** Can I limit the selection to within the SVG element?

---

## Part One

In a simple example, I have two SVGs with the same structure -- they are to be created dynamically by some javascript.  The problem: Notice that the second SVG uses the first one's gradient:

```html
<div>
  This is the first SVG, it defines "#Gradient" as red-black.
  <br>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="url('#Gradient')" />
  </svg>
</div>
    
<div>
  This is the second SVG. It ends up displaying a red-black circle instead of red-green.
  <br>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="url('#Gradient')" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Do I *really* need to insert a unique ID each time I create an SVG so that they can all work well together?

---

## Part Two

Now, suppose I actually *do* want all my SVGs to use the same `linearGradient` object. Then let's be clean about it. We will define it just once and reuse it in all other SVGs:

```html
<div>
  Let's define the linearGradient once, and use it later. No need to display this.
  <svg style="display: none;">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  Ok, let's use the linearGradient defined above. This won't work unless the above is visible -- why?
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="url('#Gradient')" />
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="50" height="50" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="url('#Gradient')" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

This doesn't work for me (Chrome), apparently because the defined SVG is inside a div with `"display: none;"`. So when referencing other SVG elements, they must be "visible" in order to be used. What's the best way to go about doing this -- should I move the defining SVG off-screen?

Comment: Yes, you really need to use unique id values. And if you are using unique id values don't put it in display:none (use some other mechanism to make it offscreen or invisible). Or stop using inline SVG and include it via an <object>, <iframe> or <img> tag.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm curious why "display: none;" breaks it -- it's technically still in the DOM, and the "display: none;" shouldn't be inherited. Is this in the specs anywhere?

Comment: Because display:none turns off CSS for the element and all descendants (per the HTML specification) and many attributes in SVG are actually handled as CSS properties e.g. fill, stop-color etc.

Comment: @RobertLongson Makes sense, thanks. As a last ditch effort to make this cleaner -- is there no option on SVG that enables its elements to be "sandboxed" to the current SVG, so that IDs do not leak? PS: I'd be happy to accept an answer if you submit one, or I can submit one myself if you prefer.

Comment: Instead of using `display:none`you can use `position:absolute; width:0;height:0; left:-10em;`

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I generate a unique ID per SVG element, using:

```js
const id = "loadericon-" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
```

And in my SVG:

```
      <defs>
        <rect
          id={id}
          width={6}
          height={14}
          x={46.5}
          y={45}
          rx={2}
          ry={2}
          transform="translate(0 -30)"
        />
      </defs>
```

Note: I use React and it is very convenient to do so.